# SSIS - execute child package parallely

Tags: ssis

What is the significance of the ExecuteOutOfProcess property in Execute Package Task in SSIS? I need to execute a child package in a for loop by passing different parameters and hoping to start several instances of the child package to execute parallely..

### Update

Found solution here (not using Execute Package Task at all)
http://www.rafael-salas.com/2010/07/ssis-how-to-run-set-of-packages.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no precedence constraint stopping the packages running in parallel, and the `MaxConcurrentExecutables` property in your package is -1 (or sufficiently large), then your execute packages tasks will run in parallel. I thought it would be obvious when running interactively.

I'm guessing 'ExecuteOutOfProcess' forces the package to run inside a new DTEXEC.EXE process. This has little bearing on whether it runs in parallel or not.

We currently have a master package which was specifically built to run processes in parallel, and none of the execute package tasks have `ExecuteOutOfProcess`

Here is some more info:

http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/11/parallel-execution-in-ssis/

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/08/27/1414.aspx

Comment: i probably should have explained my scenario better - i execute a child package in for loop. The next iteration of the loop starts only after child package has finished executing..  that is if child package executes 10 times, its done in sort of queue.. I saw the first link you provided has some information regarding using execute process task instead execute package task.. i will expplore that

Comment: Seems you're talking about _asynchronous_ execution. In this case the parent will not know the execution status of the child and might even be completed before the child does. Yes you probably can use an execute process task with DTEXEC.EXE to do this.

Comment: Used execute process task, and executed the child package at commandline using DTEXEC.EXE. It works and this soultion is flexible to accomodates several scenarios..  found this great article which has details on this approach..  http://www.rafael-salas.com/2010/07/ssis-how-to-run-set-of-packages.html

Comment: Glad you sorted it. I currently have one single for loop containing 8 execute package tests (without precedence). Each loop dynamically loads up references to multiple packages from a table. This allows me more control over the child packages and allows me to control how many will run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very robust solution for running a single SSIS package in parallel.  Please read the article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4329/performance-improvements-to-process-a-large-number-of-files-with-ssis/

This solution is different from all other solution I have found for the following reasons:

1. Uses a single SSIS package instead of multiple copies
2. Uses C# code to create multiple instances of the package
3. Uses C# code to pass different parameters to each instance
4. Uses a variable in the parent package to control the number of instances

These features make for a much simpler solution (1 package to maintain) that scales easily (adjust 1 value) yet provides true parallel processing with order of magnitude improvements in performance. Check it out.

Keith

Comment: Answers that consist only of links are usually not accepted on Stack Overflow. Could you please add some details to your answer, in case the website you linked goes down someday?

Answer (score 1):

To get some starting idea, you can have a look of these articles.

- [SSIS – RUNNING SINGLE SSIS PACKAGES IN PARALLEL TO GET FASTER PERFORMANCE FOR MULTIPLE DATA LOADS](http://gqbi.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/ssis-running-single-ssis-packages-in-parallel-to-get-faster-performance-for-multiple-data-loads/)
- [Execute multiple child packages in parallel with loop](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/execute-mutliple-child-packages-in.html)
- [Parallel execution of child SQL Server Integration Services Packages using For Loop Containers](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3138/parallel-execution-of-child-sql-server-integration-services-packages-using-for-loop-containers/)
- [Running SSIS packages In Parallel To Optimize](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/d17aa2fa-3827-43c6-a439-aa1498864f9f/running-ssis-packages-in-parallel-to-optimize)